# Selection of Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to select 2 numbers from {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} such that the sum
of the squares of the selected numbers is divisible by 5 (repetition of numbers is
allowed).

I tried just typically finding out ways and there were 5 and it is correct.
But is there a way to do it in a combinatorics way like logically?

Comment: Modulo $5$ there are three squares $0,1,4$. For sum of squares of two numbers to be divisible by $5$, both squares should either be from the class $\{0\}$ or one should be from the class $\{1\}$ and other from class $\{4\}$. Now count the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Let's solve a slightly more general problem.

Suppose we have the numbers $\{0,1,\ldots,5k-1\}$. Looking at these numbers, the squares of $k$ of them is congruent to $0\bmod 5$ (namely, the numbers divisible by $5$), the squares of $2k$ of them is congruent to $1\bmod 5$ (namely, the numbers congruent to $\pm1\bmod 5$) and the squares of the other $2k$ is congruent to $4\bmod 5$.

So, we have $k$ (distinct) zeroes, $2k$ (distinct) ones and $2k$ (distinct) fours and we want to choose two of these numbers, possibly with repetition, so that their sum is divisble by five. Of course, a zero can only be paired with another zero, so we have $k^2$ choices. A one can only be paired with a four, which gives us $4k^2$ choices. Hence, in total, we have $5k^2$ choices.